# Time Series aren't working

Tags: zingchart

I was trying to set up a Zingchart timeline series but it isn't working properly. The line is incorrect, the date doesn't get converted and the y axis shows also comepletely wrong entries.

Is there anyone who can see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        zingchart.render({
            "id":"myChart2",
            "adjustLayout": "true",

            "scale-x":{
                "transform":{
                    "type":"date",
                    "all":"%d.%m.%Y",
                    "item":{
                        "visible":"false"
                    }
                },
    "auto-fit":"true"
            },

            "data":{
                "type":"line",
                "title":{
                    "text":"Series Data Objects"
                },
                "series": [
                    {
                        "line-color":"#ff0000",
            "values": [["825552000000","248.22"],["828057600000","248.08"],["830822400000","256.50"],["833500800000","255.54"],["835920000000","259.12"],["838771200000","238.70"],["841449600000","240.49"],["844041600000","241.09"],["846633600000","241.36"],["849312000000","253.61"],["851990400000","259.85"],["854668800000","293.11"],["857088000000","297.88"],["859420800000","308.32"],["862358400000","319.51"],["864950400000","332.99"],["867628800000","359.04"],["870307200000","367.30"],["872812800000","358.41"],["875577600000","362.73"],["878256000000","335.60"],["880675200000","338.64"],["883526400000","333.78"],["886118400000","347.69"],["888624000000","374.74"],["891302400000","414.51"],["893894400000","425.38"],["896400000000","455.20"],["899164800000","449.35"],["901843200000","444.80"],["904521600000","373.21"],["907113600000","331.78"],["909792000000","350.40"],["912384000000","361.39"],["915062400000","352.06"],["917568000000","339.32"],["919987200000","351.13"],["922838400000","373.90"],["925430400000","400.78"],["928108800000","403.39"],["930700800000","411.89"],["933292800000","412.81"],["936057600000","423.43"],["938649600000","432.41"],["941328000000","434.90"],["943920000000","460.06"],["946512000000","488.37"],["949276800000","526.76"],["951782400000","546.37"],["954460800000","552.29"],["957052800000","550.44"],["959731200000","557.94"],["962323200000","565.27"],["965001600000","580.34"],["967680000000","592.46"],["970185600000","593.84"],["972950400000","586.73"],["975542400000","587.99"],["978220800000","574.41"],["980899200000","591.06"],["983318400000","584.99"],["985910400000","556.95"],["988588800000","564.08"],["991267200000","573.05"],["993772800000","562.91"],["996537600000","524.32"],["999216000000","497.57"],["1001635200000","397.34"],["1004486400000","411.61"],["1007078400000","428.81"],["1009756800000","442.50"],["1012435200000","429.54"],["1014854400000","421.18"],["1017532800000","450.53"],["1020124800000","472.24"],["1022803200000","498.40"],["1025222400000","468.36"],["1028073600000","429.21"],["1030752000000","421.15"],["1033344000000","377.54"],["1036022400000","358.54"],["1038528000000","377.31"],["1041292800000","367.59"],["1043971200000","345.28"],["1046390400000","333.31"],["1049068800000","339.64"],["1051660800000","380.18"],["1054252800000","393.14"],["1056931200000","400.88"],["1059609600000","413.35"],["1062115200000","442.21"],["1064880000000","452.48"],["1067558400000","477.75"],["1069977600000","481.48"],["1072742400000","489.31"],["1075420800000","526.61"],["1078012800000","540.60"],["1080691200000","535.48"],["1083283200000","562.73"],["1085702400000","566.69"],["1088553600000","595.42"],["1091145600000","582.42"],["1093910400000","575.98"],["1096502400000","584.63"],["1099008000000","574.38"],["1101772800000","582.98"],["1104451200000","603.91"],["1107129600000","635.69"],["1109548800000","666.30"],["1112227200000","676.75"],["1114732800000","659.07"],["1117497600000","673.11"],["1120089600000","694.10"],["1122595200000","740.74"],["1125446400000","756.92"],["1128038400000","780.60"],["1130716800000","756.80"],["1133308800000","752.26"],["1135900800000","769.52"],["1138665600000","820.12"],["1141084800000","865.22"],["1143763200000","889.63"],["1146182400000","936.09"],["1149033600000","894.71"],["1151625600000","877.78"],["1154304000000","895.81"],["1156982400000","925.75"],["1159488000000","949.28"],["1162252800000","992.61"],["1164844800000","1021.22"],["1167350400000","1089.17"],["1170201600000","1164.23"],["1172620800000","1156.02"],["1175212800000","1195.74"],["1177891200000","1293.23"],["1180569600000","1339.80"],["1183075200000","1349.97"],["1185840000000","1359.15"],["1188518400000","1330.35"],["1190937600000","1336.06"],["1193788800000","1402.84"],["1196380800000","1187.53"],["1198800000000","1302.28"],["1201737600000","1125.40"],["1204243200000","1140.95"],["1206921600000","1094.89"],["1209513600000","1142.30"],["1212105600000","1145.74"],["1214784000000","1095.27"],["1217462400000","1033.11"],["1219968000000","1055.30"],["1222732800000","931.33"],["1225411200000","708.98"],["1227744000000","621.59"],["1230595200000","616.87"],["1233273600000","603.03"],["1235692800000","552.63"],["1238457600000","539.30"],["1241049600000","638.71"],["1243555200000","684.26"],["1246320000000","695.27"],["1248998400000","742.61"],["1251676800000","791.45"],["1254268800000","813.03"],["1256860800000","796.28"],["1259539200000","773.35"],["1262131200000","802.69"],["1264723200000","839.72"],["1267142400000","823.41"],["1269993600000","893.27"],["1272585600000","918.51"],["1275264000000","887.80"],["1277856000000","877.87"],["1280448000000","905.59"],["1283212800000","917.29"],["1285804800000","950.25"],["1288310400000","997.97"],["1291075200000","1010.56"],["1293667200000","1091.59"],["1296432000000","1108.11"],["1298851200000","1125.12"],["1301529600000","1139.23"],["1304035200000","1172.38"],["1306800000000","1159.70"],["1309392000000","1079.62"],["1311897600000","992.65"],["1314748800000","910.04"],["1317340800000","842.27"],["1320019200000","865.83"],["1322611200000","835.59"],["1325203200000","827.32"],["1327968000000","889.40"],["1330473600000","939.11"],["1333065600000","947.00"],["1335744000000","952.62"],["1338422400000","890.97"],["1340928000000","892.26"],["1343692800000","900.41"],["1346371200000","892.48"],["1348790400000","918.34"],["1351641600000","917.96"],["1354233600000","908.92"],["1356652800000","934.70"],["1359590400000","992.75"],["1362009600000","1018.12"],["1364428800000","1029.32"],["1367280000000","1034.59"],["1369958400000","1048.29"],["1372377600000","1036.88"],["1375228800000","1063.80"],["1377820800000","1109.08"],["1380499200000","1140.76"],["1383177600000","1180.44"],["1385683200000","1203.78"],["1388361600000","1227.91"],["1391040000000","1266.04"],["1393545600000","1277.03"],["1396224000000","1316.99"],["1398816000000","1335.68"],["1401408000000","1326.99"],["1404086400000","1335.88"],["1406764800000","1316.64"],["1409270400000","1307.37"],["1412035200000","1264.57"],["1414713600000","1260.85"],["1417132800000","1286.13"],["1419897600000","1270.55"],["1422576000000","1149.42"],["1424995200000","1263.92"],["1427760000000","1321.38"],["1430352000000","1344.94"],["1432857600000","1355.69"],["1435622400000","1305.78"],["1438300800000","1330.99"],["1440979200000","1317.52"],["1443571200000","1296.63"],["1446163200000","1337.35"],["1448841600000","1397.59"],["1451433600000","1423.16"],["1454025600000","1358.41"],["1456704000000","1397.02"],["1459382400000","1477.83"],["1461888000000","1510.31"],["1464652800000","1584.98"],["1467244800000","1541.25"],["1469750400000","1633.75"],["1472601600000","1755.57"],["1475193600000","1781.34"],["1477872000000","1763.37"],["1480377600000","1730.74"],["1483056000000","1799.97"],["1485820800000","1888.34"],["1488240000000","2006.37"],["1490918400000","2073.79"],["1493337600000","2197.66"],["1496188800000","2250.52"],["1498780800000","2256.34"],["1501459200000","2294.53"],["1504137600000","2264.10"],["1506643200000","2350.68"],["1509062400000","2407.96"],["1512000000000","2473.35"],["1514505600000","2539.02"],["1517356800000","2590.74"],["1519776000000","2530.56"],["1521417600000","2502.57"]]
        },
                ]
            }
        });     

});         

</script>       

<div id="myChart2" class="chart"></div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fdz21jdq/42/)

Comment: please be more concrete. instead of saying: the line is incorrect, describe how the line should look like ideally. same goes for the date format (which format do you want, and which do you get?) as well as for the y axis..

Comment: I have added a link to JSFiddle, can you access it? You can see there is no date formatting and the y-axis values aren't shown correct. The curve is wrong, sometimes the prices do also sink and going up again. It is actually a time series of a fund price and should give me for each date the corresponding price in Swiss Francs.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the chart line is not displaying correctly is because of the way you formatted your values. You have your values in quotation marks like this: ["825552000000","248.22"].

The way the values should be formatted is WITHOUT quotation marks. The values should be formatted as such: [825552000000,248.22].

Once you remove the quotation marks on all of your values the chart line will display correctly.

Hope this helps.